# How to filter a dictionary using a different array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array (items) and an array of dictionaries (data) in Swift:

```
let items = ["test", "2test"]


var data = [Model(title: "Title", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text1", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "test"), 
           Model(title: "Title1", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text2", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "1test"), 
           Model(title: "Title2", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text3", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "2test")]
```

I'd like to create an array that contains those arrays of dictionaries whose "code" don't equals to the numbers provided in the 'items' array. Aka I'd like to end up with having an array of:

```
var result = [
    Model(title: "Title1", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text2", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "1test")
]
```

They seem insanely complex for this task.

Is there a clever way to do this using predicates or something else?

Comment: Please add your for loop or whatever it is you have tried so we could understand what you want to do better. And please explain what "id" is and what you mean by numbers in the `items` array, the content of that array are strings so it's very confusing when you refer to them as numbers. Also, your `Model` instances are usually not referred to as dictionaries but rather objects

Comment: `let result = data.filter { !items.contains($0.code) }` should do the trick.

Comment: But to advance in programing skills, you can to use a for loop to filter. You can start with "keep only items that have `code` equals to `"test"`, then, keep only items that don't have the `code` equals to `"test"`. Afterwards, how to keep items that have either `"test"` or `"2test"` for their `code`, and then you should how do the reverse. Then, you might use higher methods like `filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `id` I think you mean the `code` property in your `Model` as this is the only data that seems to match what is in your `items` array.

You could do something like this with `filter` on the `data` array

```
let items = ["test", "2test"]


var data = [Model(title: "Title", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text1", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "test"),
            Model(title: "Title1", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text2", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "1test"),
            Model(title: "Title2", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text3", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "2test")]

let result = data.filter { !items.contains($0.code) }
print(result)
```

This should give you:

```
[Model(title: "Title1", number: 1, weight: 10, text: "text2", url: "http://google.com", questRepeat: false, code: "1test")]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but this method does not work and an error appears  `No exact matches in call to instance method 'filter'`

Comment: @PavelZaruckov - that's odd, I ran this code and works perfectly fine. `filter` is a standard function for arrays - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter. Please also check, I fixed the spelling of `Model` in my answer.

Comment: it worked when I wrote like this  `let result = data.filter { !items.contains($0.code)  ?? true) }`